# Displaying multiple MySQL tables in one HTML table with PHP, experiencing loop trouble

Tags: php, mysql, relational-database

This is the code I am trying to use to display information from multiple MySQL tables in one table. I'm also trying to create an else clause if the table information doesn't exist. This is my failed attempt at it.

I keep editing this as I peck away at it but at this point I still can't get it to display the final else when the row doesn't exist.

```
  <?
  include"db.inc.php";//database connection
  $item = "SELECT * FROM Item";
  $result = mysql_query($item);
  while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) // Display information from Item Table.
  {
    echo ("<tr><td><a href=\"edit_item.php?id=$row[ItemID]\" target=\"_blank\">Edit</a></td>");
    echo ("<td>$row[ItemID]</td>");
    echo ("<td>$row[Category]</td>");
    echo ("<td>$row[Cost]</td>");
    echo ("<td>$row[Condition]</td>");
    echo ("<td>$row[PurchaseLot_PurchaseLotID]</td>");
    echo ("<td>$row[Location]</td>");
    echo ("<td>$row[Date]</td>");
    echo ("<td>$row[Desc]</td>");
    echo ("<td>$row[Notes]</td>");
    echo ("<td><a href=\"photo_upload.php?id=$row[ItemID]\" target=\"_blank\">Pics</a></td>");
    echo ("<td><a href=\"item_info.php?id=$row[ItemID]\" target=\"_blank\">Info</a></td></tr>");
    $info = "SELECT * FROM Info WHERE Item_ItemID = $row[ItemID] ";
    $info_results = mysql_query($info);
    while ($info_row = mysql_fetch_array($info_results))  
        {
        if ($info_row['Item_ItemID'] = $row['ItemID']) // Display Information from Info table If column exists with same ItemID.
            {
            echo ("<tr><td colspan=\"12\">");
            echo ("Manufacturer:$info_row[Manufacturer]<br>");
            echo ("Model:$info_row[Model]<br>");
            echo ("Model Number:$info_row[ModelNumber]<br>");
            echo ("Serial Number:$info_row[SerialNumber]<br>");
            echo ("Service Number:$info_row[ServiceNumber]<br>");
            echo ("</td></tr>");
            } else //else dispaly Add information to info link.
                    { 
                    echo ("<tr><td colspan=\"12\"><a href=\"item_info.php?id=$row[ItemID]\" target=\"_blank\">Add Extra Information</a></td></tr>");
                    }
        }
  }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could re-write the SQL statement in your $info `"SELECT * FROM Info"` to `"SELECT * FROM Info wHERE Item_ItemID=$row['ItemID']` ... and then delete the

```
if ($info_row['Item_ItemID'] = $row['ItemID'])
```

Plus you new a while ind your code `after $info_results = mysql_query($info);`

*** EDITED ***

then you do like this, instead of

```
while ($info_row = mysql_fetch_array($info_results))  
        {
        if ($info_row['Item_ItemID'] = $row['ItemID']) // Display Information from Info table If column exists with same ItemID.
            {
            echo ("<tr><td colspan=\"12\">");
            echo ("Manufacturer:$info_row[Manufacturer]<br>");
            echo ("Model:$info_row[Model]<br>");
            echo ("Model Number:$info_row[ModelNumber]<br>");
            echo ("Serial Number:$info_row[SerialNumber]<br>");
            echo ("Service Number:$info_row[ServiceNumber]<br>");
            echo ("</td></tr>");
            } else //else dispaly Add information to info link.
                    { 
                    echo ("<tr><td colspan=\"12\"><a href=\"item_info.php?id=$row[ItemID]\" target=\"_blank\">Add Extra Information</a></td></tr>");
                    }
        }
```

try this

```
if(mysql_num_rows($info)>0){ 
while($info_row = mysql_fetch_array($info){ 
echo ("<tr><td colspan=\"12\">");
            echo ("Manufacturer:$info_row[Manufacturer]<br>");
            echo ("Model:$info_row[Model]<br>");
            echo ("Model Number:$info_row[ModelNumber]<br>");
            echo ("Serial Number:$info_row[SerialNumber]<br>");
            echo ("Service Number:$info_row[ServiceNumber]<br>");
            echo ("</td></tr>");
} 
}else { 
echo ("<tr><td colspan=\"12\"><a href=\"item_info.php?id=$row[ItemID]\" target=\"_blank\">Add Extra Information</a></td></tr>"); 
}
```

Comment: i just figured this out I edited the code above but I still can't get it to display my else clause.

Comment: then you do like this instead if(mysql_num_rows($info)>0){ while($info_row = mysql_fetch_array($info){   echo ("<tr><td colspan=\"12\">");
            echo ("Manufacturer:$info_row[Manufacturer]<br>");
            ....
            echo ("</td></tr>"); } }else { echo ("<tr><td colspan=\"12\"><a href=\"item_info.php?id=$row[ItemID]\" target=\"_blank\">Add Extra Information</a></td></tr>"); }

Answer (score 0):

i try to edit your code but im not able to try it.

```
<?
  include"db.inc.php";//database connection
  $item = "SELECT * FROM Item";
  $result = mysql_query($item);
  while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) // Display information from Item Table.
  {
    echo ("<tr><td><a href=\"edit_item.php?id=$row[ItemID]\" target=\"_blank\">Edit</a></td>");
    echo ("<td>$row[ItemID]</td>");
    echo ("<td>$row[Category]</td>");
    echo ("<td>$row[Cost]</td>");
    echo ("<td>$row[Condition]</td>");
    echo ("<td>$row[PurchaseLot_PurchaseLotID]</td>");
    echo ("<td>$row[Location]</td>");
    echo ("<td>$row[Date]</td>");
    echo ("<td>$row[Desc]</td>");
    echo ("<td>$row[Notes]</td>");
    echo ("<td><a href=\"photo_upload.php?id=$row[ItemID]\" target=\"_blank\">Pics</a></td>");
    echo ("<td><a href=\"item_info.php?id=$row[ItemID]\" target=\"_blank\">Info</a></td></tr>");
    $info = "SELECT * FROM Info where Item_ItemID = ".$row['ItemID'];
    $info_results = mysql_query($info);
    if ($info_row = mysql_fetch_array($info_results))  
        {
            echo ("<tr><td colspan=\"12\">");
            echo ("Manufacturer:$info_row[Manufacturer]<br>");
            echo ("Model:$info_row[Model]<br>");
            echo ("Model Number:$info_row[ModelNumber]<br>");
            echo ("Serial Number:$info_row[SerialNumber]<br>");
            echo ("Service Number:$info_row[ServiceNumber]<br>");
            echo ("</td></tr>");
        } 
        else { //else dispaly Add information to info link.
            echo ("<tr><td colspan=\"12\"><a href=\"item_info.php?id=$row[ItemID]\" target=\"_blank\">Add Extra Information</a></td></tr>");
         }        
  }
  ?>
```

i hope this is the answer.